# Joining CSV files together using Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have some problems with joining CSV files together. I successfully joined 4 files using Pandas`.join` method. But now when I want to join next files, I can't do that. [image]

Comment: Please can you edit your post with your raw data, code to recreate your df, the desired output, any errors, and your code. Links to images are counter-productive on SO

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways join two data frames (eventually csv) in pandas. The three ways include :

1. **Merge**

df1.merge(df2)

Merge allows you to merge two data frames by index. You can learn more here :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

2. **Concat**

   pd.concat([df1, df2])

   Concat allows you to join two dataframes by axis. Lear more about concat here :
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html
3. **Join**

   df1.join(df2)

   Join operation allows you to join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key column. Efficiently Join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once by passing a list. Learn more about it here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html